# R recognizes folder as file

Tags: r, file, file-io

I've got a folder on Dropbox where I store my R scripts, and a sub-folder of that folder where I archive older versions of those scripts. For whatever reason, 4 of my scripts have a ".R" extension, and one has a ".r" extension. Both work fine when loaded and run.

I want to get a list of the files in this folder, which I do with `list.files()`. If I just specify the folder path, then I get a list with 6 elements: my 5 scripts and the archive folder.

If I specify `pattern = "*.R"` then I get the 4 files with that file extension. If I also specify `ignore.case = TRUE` then the returned list does contain my fifth script, but for some crazy reason the archive folder shows up again!

Why is a folder apparently being recognized as a file with extension "*.r"?

Comment: What is the name of this folder? Something like "archiveR"? Note that in regular expressions, "." (dot) matches any single character. "\*.R" is not really a valid regex, though it doesn't seem to throw and error. "\*" is  typically used following some character or subexpression to mean zero more more of such expressions.

Comment: what's the folder name? you must have a lower-case "r" in the folder name somewhere

Comment: Thanks @lmo, @Eric, the archive folder name was "archive". I replaced `.` with `\\.` and this seems to be giving the desired behaviour.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both [lmo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4895725/lmo) and [Eric](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7091646/eric) correctly guessed that my greedy regular expression was matching the folder because its name contained an "r". I had forgotten to escape the `.`, and after doing so the issue was resolved. Perhaps even better would be to add the end of line character "$" at the end of the match (e.g. `*\\.r$`).